# spring-mongodb fails to save in UTF-8

Tags: spring, mongodb

We are inserting documents in mongo through spring-mongodb and the mongo-java-driver everything seems to work fine on the program. Accessing the data back through the java driver works fine but doing the same through mongo console breaks the console.

```
> db.item.find()
error:non ascii character detected
>
```

I saw there was a JIRA ticket with a similar error but I'm not sure if this problem is just a console proble or there is really something going on the server.

Comment: Is the data correct (is that what you mean by 'works fine')? What version of mongoDB are you using? What is the JIRA ticket you found? Where are you running MongoDB? Did you get prebuilt binaries for MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that you are running on a UTF-8 enabled build of MongoDB. A common problem apparently is doing a custom build (or running an older build) of MongoDB without UTF-8 support. The 10gen supplied binaries should have this enabled by default. If they do not, this is often the [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5280).

Comment: Yes the problem was and old Mongo shell. Works on mongo shell 2.2.3. Ubuntu users, beware of mongodb installation referenced by your repository, setup from a mongo site manual download to ensure latest versions.